# I have had 500gb HD this whole time but my system has only been showing 250gb on my Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

So basically like the title says I have had a 500GB Hard disk this whole time but my C drive has only been showing about 250GB in total. I only noticed this because I opened my laptop and saw the Hard drive had 500GB.  I checked my disk with the `diskpart` command and listed  the disk and volume and got this
[image]

You see that I should have 227GB free but it shows only like 8GB free on my system. Doing my research it seems like a partition on my hard drive is responsible. So what can I do next to gain the full space without causing my current files on my hard drive to be deleted? It is very important that the suggestion given doesn't cause any deletion on my hard drive. Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screenshot of Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc). That will be clearer on exactly what is going on. And gives us a better idea what to recommend.

Comment: What make is your disk?

Comment: Yes, a disk management screenshot would help someone answer the question more precisely rather than guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: disk management]

Using disk management to reclaim the hard drive does not erase your information. Instead, it allows you to specify the size of the unallocated space that you want to add to the C drive without having any of your data lost.

To do this, select the drive you want to extend; as an example, I clicked C.
[image]

Enter the size of the unallocated space you want to add; when you have put the required number you want, click Next, then Finish.